# ImportError: No module named nltk (python 2.5, python 2.7.9, nltk, Anaconda)

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, anaconda, python-2.5

I am new to Python and NLP. And I wanted to start NLP self learning. So here's what I did. 
I had both Python 25 and Python 27 installed in my computer. Then I downloaded and installed Anaconda setup. When i open a python IDLE, always Python 2.5 IDLE gets open. To get a higher version of IDLE opened, I then installed Python 2.7.9. Then I could open Python 2.7.9 IDLE. Even though I have installed Anaconda and it has nltk 3.0.2, I get an errors saying 'ImportError: No module named nltk' when nltk is imported. So I downloaded and installed nltk 3.0.3. But still I get the same error. Can someone tell me what has gone wrong?

Comment: what is your default python now type python in cmd and see

Comment: I got this when I typed Python in command prompt ->  Python 2.7.9 :Anaconda 2.2.0 <64 bit>

Comment: that shows that your default is anaconda version type import nltk there and see if the problem prevails'

Comment: I typed `import nltk` in iPython console in nothing happened. Then I typed `from nltk.book import*` and then following error messages were printed saying LookupError. Why do I get that?

Comment: After importing nltk you should run `nltk.download()` to download all wanted methods and datas then type your import